Insert data from CTE to table in Teradata
I have a script with a series of CTEs. I want to update a database table from the final CTE, but I can't seem to do that. How can I update a db table using data from my CTE?
Simplified example of what I'm trying to do:
WITH cte_2 AS (
SELECT 
    ID
    , MEMBER_STATE
    , PLAN_CODE
FROM cte_1
)

INSERT INTO database_table (ID, MEMBER_STATE, PLAN_CODE)
SELECT 
    ID
    , MEMBER_STATE
    , PLAN_CODE
FROM cte_2


the insert into ...  part goes before you define the CTE.   As an very simplified example: insert into <your table> with cte as (select * from <other table> select * from cte;
